# Error while passing id of field as variable for javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have multiple forms created using for loop and I'm passing the field Id which is unique for all forms and fields to the javascript method but it is not reading the value using id.

Any other way to send the id so that I can get the exact field value in the javascript for ajax processing. Any help would be much appreciable.

```html
<%
  String js = "Id" + count;
%>

<input name='Id' label=""  id='Id<%=count%>'  style="width:100px;" onChange="javascript:getName('<%=js %>')" />
```

```js
function getName(count) {
  String field = count;
  var field1 = document.getElementById(field).value;
  alert(field1);
}
```

Whereas `field1` is showing `null`

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('Id' + field).value`

Comment: Is the second code block Java or JS? If it's JS then `String` will be giving you a syntax error

Comment: Second code block is javascript.

Comment: In which case change `String` to `var` and your code will work.

Comment: Now it is giving error **cannot read the value of null** in browser console. When I change the String to var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the following code `String field = count;` is incorrect you need to replace `String` by `var` because this is how JavaScript variables declartion work, but anyway you can get rid of this line.

And your JS will be:

```
function getName(count) {
  var field1 = document.getElementById(count).value;
  alert(field1);
}
```

**Optimisation:**

Note that you can pass the `id` directly in your JSP like this:

```
<input name='Id' label=""  id='Id<%=count%>'  style="width:100px;" onChange="javascript:getName(this.value)" />
```

And in your JS:

```
function getName(count) {
   alert(count);
}
```

Comment: this.value will give the value of the textbox and then you are trying to find the element with that value by using  as an id. Its totally wrong

Comment: @Sahil that's what the OP tried to do in the first place.

Comment: No it wasn't wrong code, it was just containing useless lines of code, but it was correct and just having an additionnal step.

Comment: @sahil you can check it in the edit revision, you will see that it was corerct, stop being so rude and have some fair play.

Comment: See here your recent code: `<input name='Id' label=""  id='Id<%=count%>'  style="width:100px;" onChange="javascript:getName('Id'+this.value)" />`
And your JS will be:

`function getName(count) {
 // here you are doing wrong u actually getting the value of the field concatinated with Id string and then finding that in the DOM var field1 = document.getElementById(count).value;
  alert(field1);
}`

Comment: And this isn't wrong because in the JS `count` will be passed as `'Id'+this.value` and it's the correct `id`.

Comment: from where it is correct see the https://jsfiddle.net/1b8khr03/ and check the count alert value. You will never get an dom element with that

Comment: its not the id :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
function getName(count) {
 // String field = count;
 var field = count;
 var field1 = document.getElementById(field).value;
 alert(field1);
 }
```

Javascript supports creating variables by using the var keyword not the String.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Giving "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: check by alert(field) did u get the correct id of the field?

Comment: @Sahil `alert(field)` won't be reached here because the Error was thrown before this line.

Comment: @chsdk i mean before this line ` var field1 = document.getElementById(field).value;`

Comment: Ah ok, got it you can use `console.log(field)` instead and check it in your browser console.

Comment: @chsdk thanks for your answer which you had deleted from that I got hint. and How its working fine.

Comment: @ShahbazKhan Yes I included some useless code in the first place, so I deleted my answer so I can edit it to fix that point, but it leads you now to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 onChange="javascript:getName(this)"
```

And in javascript

```
function getName(ref) {
    var id= ref.id;
    alert(id);
  }
```